# How to find the limit of $\dfrac{\ln(\ln(\frac{n}{n-1}))}{\ln(n)}$?

Tags: analysis, limits, logarithms

How do you find

$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \dfrac{\ln(\ln(\frac{n}{n-1}))}{\ln(n)}$$

I know it's $-1$, but I had to plot it.

Comment: What do you mean to plot it? The limit?

Comment: I meant drawing the graph of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** You can use L'hopital's rule twice.

**Added:** If you use L'hopital's rule twice then you get the expression

$$ -\frac{n}{n-1}. $$

**Another approach:**

$$  \dfrac{\ln(\ln(\frac{n}{n-1}))}{\ln(n)} =  \dfrac{\ln(-\ln(1-\frac{1}{n}))}{\ln(n)}= \dfrac{\ln(-(-\frac{1}{n}-O(\frac{1}{n^2})))}{\ln(n)}\sim \frac{\ln(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}=-\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n)}=-1.$$

Note that, in the above derivations, we used the Taylor series of $$\ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\dots\,,$$

and the following property of $\ln(x)$

$$ \ln(1/a) = -\ln(a). $$

Comment: Thanks, I like the second approach the most!

Comment: @Xiign: You are welcome. So do I. You need to be familiar with The Taylor series. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

What is $\lim_{n \to \infty}  \dfrac{n}{n-1}$ ?

Convert the expression into $\dfrac{\pm \infty}{\infty}$ form. Then you have L'hoptial's rule.

Answer (score 1):

If $0\le x\le 1$, then $x\ln 2 \le \ln(1+x)\le x$. (This inequality follows that $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$ is concave function.) Since $x\mapsto \ln(1+x)$ is order-preserving, so
$$\frac{\ln\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)}{\ln n}\le \frac{\ln \frac{1}{n-1}}{\ln n}=-\frac{\ln (n-1)}{\ln n}$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and
$$\frac{\ln\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)}{\ln n}\ge \frac{\ln \left( \frac{1}{n-1}\ln 2\right)}{\ln n}=-\frac{\ln (n-1)-\ln 2}{\ln n}$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore
$$-\frac{\ln (n-1)-\ln 2}{\ln n}\le \dfrac{\ln(\ln(\frac{n}{n-1}))}{\ln(n)} \le- \frac{\ln (n-1)}{\ln n}$$
and take $n\to\infty$ each side of inequality then we get desired result.

Comment: There's a minus sign missing in your last inequality.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach. Let $n=e^m$ and look at the limit a $m\to\infty$. You get
$$
\frac{\log\log\frac{e^m}{e^m-1}}{\log e^m}=\frac{\log\log\left(1+\frac{1}{e^m-1}\right)}{m}
$$

Since clearly $\frac{1}{e^m-1}\to0$ you can use the approximation $\log(1+x)\approx x$. Then you have
$$
\frac{\log\left(\frac{1}{e^m-1}\right)}{m}=\frac{-\log(e^m-1)}{m}\approx\frac{-m}{m}=-1
$$